# How can I copy all .rodata section using onjcopy?

Tags: gcc

I've tried:

```
objcopy -j .rodata ...
```

but it copies only the ".rodata" section to the output file.

However, gcc creates ".rodata.str*" sections for read-only strings! And objcopy doesn't seem to recognize those string sections.

How can I extract the whole .rodata section including all string sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer by myself right after asking this question...

To dump all .rodata sections to a single file, you just need to use wildcard:

```
objcopy -j .rodata* ...
```